# Logging.properties in WAR file ignored by Liberty server

Tags: java, logging, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I have a Maven java project, my logging.properties is placed under resources folder. I have configured to print FINE level messages using console logger.

The WAR file generated has the properties file under WEB-INF/classes but, the application when deployed and executed, I can see only INFO level logs.

Should i initialize any LogConfiguration apart from having my logging.properties in the correct path ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As describe [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSRTLW_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html), you configure loggers in Liberty by something like this in the server.xml:

`<logging traceSpecification="*=audit:com.myco.mypackage.*=debug"/>`

and see the [logging metatype](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRTLW_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/autodita/rwlp_metatype_4ic.html?view=kc#mtFile144) doc to configure other aspects like log file size, number of logs to keep, etc.

Or, as the article mentions, you can use the *bootstrap.properties* 
entries to do the same, e.g. **com.ibm.ws.logging.trace.specification**.

Though WebSphere also supports *java.util.logging* APIs, its full infrastructure isn't necessarily configured the same way as say Tomcat, which your app may be patterned after.

If you want to configure different logging behavior for different applications you can have the application Java code use a different Logger name for each, and then configure them differently through the single server.xml config (or also potentially separate the apps out onto different servers).

Dynamically changing the trace settings on a running server can be done simply by editing the server.xml config (as can dynamically configuring almost any aspect of Liberty).